# Office 365 Management API in Azure Active Directory Enterprise Application

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365api, office365-apps

I have found there's the Office 365 Management API in Azure Active Directory Enterprise Application as attached after I have grant Office 365 API access to one of my registered app.

I'm wondering what impact would I face if I delete the Office 365 Management API in Azure Active Directory Enterprise Application?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I know, if you delete Office 365 Management API, you just cannot use it anymore, and there is no impact for the registered app.

Comment: Thank you, could you please provide some details about "you just cannot use it anymore"?

Answer (score 0):

When you registered your application under App Registrations, gave it permissions to the API and then performed the consent to those permissions...it automatically creates the registration in Enterprise Applications.  Basically, the registration under Enterprise Applications is the instance of the app for that directory (tenant).  If the app was multi-tenant, it would also need to be registered in Enterprise Applications in the other tenants needing to access the application.  If you remove the registration from under Enterprise Applications it will remove access to the app for that tenant.  In order for users in that tenant to regain access to the application, the app would need to be re-registered under Enterprise Applications and the consent would have to happen again.